# Is it possible to have lossy coupled class for one-to-many relationships in CoreData? (Something similar to @Embedded as in Android Room ORM)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am reading tutorial of one-to-many relation for CoreData - https://cocoacasts.com/one-to-many-and-many-to-many-core-data-relationships/

1. An `Account` can have many `Users`
2. Each `User` can have one `Account`

From the tutorial, we end up with classes **tightly coupled** with each others.

1. `Account` has list of `User`s as class member.
2. `User` has `Account` as class member.

---

### How to achieve lossy copuled in Android

In Android Room (ORM library for Android), we are able to avoid such tightly coupled class design. We will have another "container" class, which hold `Account` object and list of `User` objects.

The key for this solution, is to use [@Embedded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx4lH.png) feature.

```
public class AccountWithUser {
    @Embedded
    public Account account;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "accountId", entity = User.class)
    public List<User> users;
}

@Entity(tableName = "account")
public class Account {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    public int id;
}

@Entity(tableName = "user")
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "account_id")
    public int accountId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    public int firstName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    public long lastName;
}
```

If we look at the generated SQLite table, it looks as following

### Account table

[image]

### User table

[image]

From the above Android design, you can see `Account` and `User` classes are pretty lossy coupled.

---

I was wondering, does CoreData has similar `@Embedded` feature, so that we can achieve **lossy coupled** class for one-to-many relationships?

Comment: Core Data is loosely coupled when you use relationships. The `Account` holds a set of identifiers for the `User` objects. It doesn’t hold the `User` objects directly. The reference is a set of foreign keys to use SQL terminology (but don’t think of Core Data as a database, it is an object persistence system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not much experience in Android ORM, but having 3 Class for 2 SQL Tables seems like a big inconvenience. The most popular Hibernate ORM does it the other way round, for a many-to-many relationship, where you create 2 Class for 3 SQL Tables.

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many

I have checked the reasoning for Room ORM here:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data#understand-no-object-references

It seems like this "restriction" is to prevent developers from having performance or memory issues.

> However, this seemingly innocent change causes the Author table to be
>   queried on the main thread.

This is quite common in iOS, to hit the database to get a lazy loaded related object to poopulate a row in a TableView. Most of the creation of rows in a table are done in

tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview

which I believe is not run in the main thread.

Most of the time some sort of background loading will be needed only when it is loading an image, of loading something from external, then we will use the DispatchQueue

https://nghiatran.me/advanced-issues-the-right-way-to-load-content-in-backgrounds-thread-with-tableview/